# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignTop' with value '@id/imageView3')

Tags: android, manifest

This:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"/>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

is my AndroidManifest.xml and I get the error:

Error:(77, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignTop' with value '@id/imageView3').

Error:(78, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/imageView3').

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? Eclipse or Android Studio ?

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya solve my question, I forgot to add "+ sign" at first .

Comment: And it's working on Android Studio

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use . Add `+` sign at first .

```
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
```

After that, **Clean-Rebuild-Restart** Your `IDE`  .

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It works indeed but I don't understand why we need the '+' here. I thought @+id meant that we wanted to CREATE a new id, not to refer to an existing one. This to me looks like a workaround to hide something. As a matter of fact, there are cases where I did not need this hack although I was using the same layout. If someone knows more I'd be interested...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing, but then my problem was that I had accidentally moved a view above the the view it was referencing.

Original code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_view">
    <LinearLayout
        ... >
        ... 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then I adjusted it to something like

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_view">
    <LinearLayout
        ... >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view2"
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_view">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I was weird because the IDE was indicating an error for the line

```
android:layout_below="@id/image_view"
```

inside the second ImageView, so it took me a while before I noticed that the error was really in the

```
android:layout_below="@id/image_view"
```

in the ScrollView that I forgot to remove.